# Sysprep's generalize option cleaning the windows installation too far

Tags: windows-11, sysprep, bare-metal

I'm trying to build a lean & clean Windows 11 WIM. Here's my approach so far:

I would go to Audit Mode by selecting Audit Mode & reboot at C:\Windows\system32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe. After reboot, I would select to OOBE, shutdown & generalize on the Sysprep instance that is left pre-opened. Then, I power up again on a recovery/portable Windows environment (Paragon HDM or Windows installation media), interrupting the normal installed Windows boot-up, & where I can run DISM to build the WIM.

The problem is, generalize seems to have left my laptop too bare & it can't boot up anymore. I can't get pass "Getting ready".

---

If it matters:

This is a customized Windows install in that right after when the installation files were copied & the the first restart were to happen, it was interrupted. Then C:\PerfLogs, C:\ProgramData, C:\Temp & C:\Users were moved to D:\ & these aforementioned directories where made junction links to their new location in D:\PerfLogs, D:\ProgramData, D:\Temp & D:\Users.

---

Additional info:

At the point where I can't get pass "Getting ready" & instead boot to a Windows environment (Paragon HDM or Windows installation media), the installed Windows partition is not assigned a letter & the supposed D: is drive C:

Might have I messed up the GPT of the drive?

Comment: I power up again on a recovery/portable Windows environment  ... That has been deprecated so far as I know. Sysprep is designed to use with a full Windows operating system.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. After choosing OOBE, shutdown & generalize, I boot to a Windows environment other that the installed one. So to avoid having to call DISM online. Sysprep, I only have called within the installed Windows.

Comment: If that is so, the the options you chose for Sysprep may have eliminated too much. Otherwise Sysprep generally works.

Comment: Re-read **If it matters** & **Additional info**. My suspicion is there.

Comment: Where I have worked with people using Sysprep, we have not changed the main partition so I cannot answer that.

Comment: Sysprep removes hardware drivers (does not delete them) and any user account and sid, not much more.>>>>>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation?view=windows-11

Comment: More info on generalize>>>>>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep-command-line-options?view=windows-11